# Почему не передается данная строка на мейл?

Tags: php, html

Не могу понять почему не передается поле артикул на почту? Вот код html:

```
<b><div class="feedcall" style="background: none;">
<div class="feedcall_center">
<div class="title">
<h1>Отследить груз по артикулу</h1>
</div>
<div class="pre_form">Оставьте ваши контакты и мы свяжемся с вами.</div>
<div class="form_elem"><input class="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" /></div>
<div class="form_elem"><input class="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон" /></div>
<div class="form_elem"><input class="art" name="art" type="text" placeholder="Ваш артикул" /></div>
<div class="form_elem">
<div class="send_feedcall">Отправить сообщение</div>
</div>
</div>
</div></b>
```

И код php:

```
{
  if($_POST['ajax'] == "backphone")
  { ////////////////  ЗАКАЗ ОБРАТНОГО ЗВОНКА  /////////////////////////////////////////////

    $jsonData = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsonData']));

    $errors = "";
    $error1 = "";
    $error2 = "";
    $gooddata = array();

    foreach($jsonData as $k => $v) {

      $v = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(trim($v)));
      switch ($k)
      {
        case "name":
        case "phone":
          if (empty($v))
          {
            $error1 = "Вы заполнили не все поля обязательные для заполнения";
          }
          break;
        case "art": 
        case "email":
          if (empty($v))
          {
            $error1 = "Вы заполнили не все поля обязательные для заполнения";
          }

          if (!empty($v) && strpos($v, '@') === false)
          {
            $error2 = "Email адрес не корректный";
          }
          break;
        case "message":
      }

      $gooddata[$k] = $v;
    }

    if ($error1 != '' || $error2 != '')
    {
      if($error1 != '')
      {
        $errors .= $error1.'<br />';
      }

      if($error2 != '')
      {
        $errors .= $error2;
      }

      echo $errors;
    }
    else
    {
      $to      = get_settings('admin_mail');
      $subject = "Заказ обратного звонка";
      $message = '
              <table border="0">
                <tr>
                  <td>Имя:</td>
                  <td><b>'.$gooddata['name'].'</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Телефон:</td>
                  <td><b>'.$gooddata['phone'].'</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Email:</td>
                  <td><b>'.$gooddata['email'].'</b></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>Артикул:</td>
                  <td><b>'.$gooddata['art'].'</b></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>Примечание:</td>
                  <td><b>'.$gooddata['message'].'</b></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              ';

      if (feedback_send_mail($to, $subject, $message))
      {
        echo 'ok';
        $feed_result = true;
      }
      else
      {
        echo 'При отправке заявки возникли проблемы, попробуйте повторить позже';
      }
    }
    exit;
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'Ошибка, попробуйте повторить отправку заказа позже';
    exit;
  }
```

Comment: Ошибок нет, письмо на почту уходит, но вместо артикула - пустота?

Comment: Странная часть внутри case "art": email":, не понимаю ее. Применительно к art: если пустое значение - ошибка. Если не пустое значение art и в нем нет @ - ошибка. Может стоит art перенести от email к name, phone?